# Any words meaning a situation when you can't joke?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

I'm looking for a word that can be used in several situations:

- a moment when you cannot joke
- a subject that you can't joke about
- a person who doesn't understand your joke

And I wonder if there are any adjectives that represent above situation or moment or subject or person.

What I found so far is "jokeless", but it sounds like "not funny" differ from what I want.
If there is an adjective, 'inhumorable', that might be it.

Comment: Hi Minime, this kind of single word request is off-topic here at writing.se. But is accepted over at [english.se]. I've gone ahead and migrated your question for you. Good luck!

Comment: You are looking for one word that works as an adjective for #1 and #2 and as a noun for #3? I don't think that's possible. But *sacrosanct* works for #1 and #2:  *treated as if holy : immune from criticism or violation*. *This moment is sacrosanct. This subject is sacrosanct.*

Comment: A person who doesn't understand joke can usually be a teacher :)

Comment: @linksassin Thank you for moving my question on proper location!

Answer (score 5):

Some adjectives that come to mind are *serious, grave, solemn*.

"solemnity" can be useful as a noun, for example:

- There was no room for jokes due to the solemnity of the occasion.

Answer (score 3):

The term is *Serious*.

In common usage if the current situation will not permit humor one might be told, "This is serious." or "This is a serious situation." Once stated the joker knows where he stands and what a reception he will get with his five minutes of Vegas. This will cover both the moment asked about and the subject. One who cannot understand a joke is called *Clueless*. This is a different idea since it is not that they are too serious to understand, they just don't. One may be too serious to enjoy or permit a joke but they get it even if they would rather not.